# Query optimization for inner joins in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have a database with 3 tables,  masterInfo, primDescT, secDescT.

```
CREATE TABLE masterInfo (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
primDescId INTEGER,
secDescId INTEGER,
category INTEGER,
UNIQUE(primDescId, secDescId, category));

CREATE TABLE primDescT (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
primDesc nvarchar(512));

CREATE TABLE secDescT (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
secDesc nvarchar(512));

INSERT INTO primDescT VALUES(1,'XXXX');
INSERT INTO primDescT VALUES(2,'YYYY');
INSERT INTO primDescT VALUES(3,'ZZZZ');
INSERT INTO primDescT VALUES(4,'SSSS');

INSERT INTO secDescT VALUES(1,'AAA');
INSERT INTO secDescT VALUES(2,'BBB');
INSERT INTO secDescT VALUES(3,'CCC');

INSERT INTO masterInfo VALUES(1,1,1,1);
INSERT INTO masterInfo VALUES(2,2,2,2);
INSERT INTO masterInfo VALUES(3,3,1,1);
INSERT INTO masterInfo VALUES(4,4,3,2);
```

Tables, masterInfo has 1765137 rows, 312210 rows in primDescT, 105458 rows in secDescT.

I have used the below query to fetch the results.

```
SELECT m.id AS pId, 
primDesc AS pDescr, secDesc AS sDescr, category   AS category 
FROM masterInfo m
INNER JOIN primDescT ON primDescT.id = m.primDescId
INNER JOIN secDescT ON secDescT.id = m.secDescId
WHERE m.category IN ('1','2') ORDER BY pDescr ASC  LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0
```

Above query takes 8 seconds to response.

But if i set the offset as 1756300, then it will take 53 seconds.

```
SELECT m.id AS pId, 
primDesc AS pDescr, secDesc AS sDescr, category   AS category 
FROM masterInfo m
INNER JOIN primDescT ON primDescT.id = m.primDescId
INNER JOIN secDescT ON secDescT.id = m.secDescId
WHERE m.category IN ('1','2') ORDER BY pDescr ASC  LIMIT 100 OFFSET 1756300
```

How can i optimize the above queries to fetch within 3 seconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with these queries is the ORDER BY: all the results must be computed before the database can determine which the 100 or 1756400 smallest ones are. [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) output:

```
0,0,0,SCAN TABLE masterInfo AS m
0,1,1,SEARCH TABLE primDescT USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
0,2,2,SEARCH TABLE secDescT USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
0,0,0,USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
```

To remove the explicit sorting step, you must index that column:

```
CREATE INDEX pd ON primDescT(primDesc);
```

And you must force the database to use this index (by default, SQLite ignores LIMIT when estimating query costs, and if you wanted all results, not using the `pd` index would be faster):

```
SELECT ...
FROM masterInfo m
INNER JOIN primDescT INDEXED BY pd ON primDescT.id = m.primDescId
--                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
INNER JOIN secDescT ON secDescT.id = m.secDescId
WHERE ...
ORDER BY pDescr ASC
LIMIT 100 OFFSET ...;
```

```
0,0,1,SCAN TABLE primDescT USING COVERING INDEX pd
0,1,0,SEARCH TABLE masterInfo AS m USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_masterInfo_1 (primDescId=?)
0,2,2,SEARCH TABLE secDescT USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
```

A large OFFSET value is always slow; the database must compute and throw away all these rows.

If you are using paging, you can replace the OFFSET with a lookup on the sorting column; this requires that you save the last value of the previous page:

```
SELECT ...
FROM masterInfo m
INNER JOIN primDescT INDEXED BY pd ON primDescT.id = m.primDescId
INNER JOIN secDescT ON secDescT.id = m.secDescId
WHERE primDesc > :LastValue
--    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  AND ...
ORDER BY pDescr ASC
LIMIT 100 /* no offset */;
```

Comment: I have the pagination, where user can navigate the nth page. So, I think, Using Lastvalue will not be useful.